# Grails removes parameters from script tag

Tags: javascript, grails

In a GSP of my Grails 2.3.4 project, I'm trying to add parameter:

```
<script src="js/pages/item.js?timestamp=${grailsApplication.config.grails.itemproj.resource.version}"/></script>
```

In HTML script tag is with parameter (which is working fine)
but in the Chrome's Networking tab, I'm getting `js/pages/item.js`. How can I manage it?

Comment: if you have solved this maybe you can answer your own question to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made change in my config.groovy file 
from:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

to:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/plugins/*']
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<script src="js/pages/item.js?timestamp='${grailsApplication.config.grails.itemproj.resource.version}'">&nbsp;</script>
```

Are you sure you have an entry in the Config.groovy file??

Comment: yes of course I have in config this property, I tried your example it doesn't work

Comment: substitute with this grailsApplication.config and try to inspect with chrome developer tools

Comment: can you include a snapshot of your Config.groovy?